# Is there any logical issue in this mergesort...?where is it failing

Tags: java, arrays, mergesort

Main function with two arrays being passed in mergeSort function one original array and 2nd temp array for storing sorted values in it.

I'm getting output as temp = [3 2 6 4 7 8 5 8 1] when I'm printing temp in the main function after merge sort.

```
static void main(String args[])
    {
          int arr[] = {6,4,7,8,5,3,2,8,1};
          int temp[] = new int[arr.length];
     
          for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++)
          {
          temp[i] = arr[i];
          } 
          mergeSort(arr, temp, 0, arr.length-1);
          
          for(int num : temp)
          {
             System.out.print(num+" ")
          } 
    }

//merge function comparing array and assigning to a new temp array.
static void merge(int arr[],int temp[], int l, int mid, int r)
    {     
         int i = l;
         int j = mid+1;
         
         int index=l;
         while(i<=mid && j<=r)
         {   
             if(arr[i]<=arr[j])
             { 
                temp[index] = arr[i];
                i++;
             }
             else
             {
                temp[index] = arr[j];
                j++;
             }
             index++;
         }     
         while(i<=mid)
             {
                 temp[index] = arr[i];
                 i++;  
                 index++;   
             }
             
         while(j<=r)
             {
                 temp[index] = arr[j];
                 j++;
                 index++;
             }
    }

//mergeSort function
static void mergeSort(int arr[],int temp[], int l, int r)
        {
            if(l<r)
        {
           int mid = l + (r-l)/2;
           mergeSort(arr,temp,l,mid);
           mergeSort(arr,temp,mid+1,r);
           merge(arr,temp,l,mid,r);
        } 
        }
```

I have passed two arrays in the mergeSort function. One is original which is `arr` and the second is `temp` array in which I'm storing sorted elements.

Answer (score 0):

In your `merge`, the `arr` needs to be reassigned each time, otherwise, the previous merge result is useless. (It's always the same arr that you started with)

```
static void merge(int arr[],int temp[], int l, int mid, int r)
    {
        int i = l;
        int j = mid+1;
        for (int k = l; k < r + 1; k++) {
            arr[k] = temp[k];
        }
        int index=l;
        while(i<=mid && j<=r)
        {
            if(arr[i]<=arr[j])
            {
                temp[index] = arr[i];
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                temp[index] = arr[j];
                j++;
            }
            index++;
        }
        while(i<=mid)
        {
            temp[index] = arr[i];
            i++;
            index++;
        }

        while(j<=r)
        {
            temp[index] = arr[j];
            j++;
            index++;
        }
    }
```